# Moving a player around a board, by choice and by chance

Tags: c#, unity3d

Recently I had to add 2 different sets of logic for moving my player around the board. One lets the player pick a location and move him there while the other uses a dice. I'm reusing code for both cases and would like to "merge" them into one thing. Any help and suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
void Update()
{
    #region Target Game Mdoe
    if (gameManager.gameMode == GameMode.Target)
    {
        if (currentTile != targetTile && time != 0 && !waitingForCard && isTurn)
        {
            movementProgress += movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
            nextSquare = FindNextSquare();
            ChangeCharDirection();


            while (nextSquare != null && movementProgress >= 1.0f)
            {
                movementProgress -= 1.0f;
                travelledTiles.Push(currentTile);
                TriggerTilePassBy();
                currentTile = nextSquare;
                if (currentTile != targetTile)
                {

                    nextSquare = FindNextSquare();

                    TriggerTilePassBy();
                    if (currentTile.tyleType != TyleType.IntersectionTyle)
                    {
                        time--;
                        gameManager.world_ui_Controller.UpdateUI(id);
                    }
                }
                if (currentTile != targetTile && time == 0)
                {
                    hasToSkipTurn = true;
                    Transform[] playerSpots = GetPlayerSpots();
                    StartCoroutine(LerpToPlayerSpot(playerSpots[id].position, Constants.GetInPosTime));
                    HandleTyleType(currentTile);
                    targetTile = currentTile;
                }
                else if (currentTile == targetTile)
                {
                    HandleTyleType(currentTile);
                    // nextSquare = FindNextSquare();
                    nextSquare = null;
                    currDir = PlayerStatus.Still;
                    SetAnimatorBools();
                }
            }
            if (nextSquare != null && targetTile != null)
            {
                transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(currentTile.transform.position, nextSquare.transform.position, movementProgress);
                currDir = PlayerStatus.Moving;
                SetAnimatorBools();
            }
            else
            {
                movementProgress = 0.0f;
                // gameManager.camController.EnableCameraDrag();
                Transform[] playerSpots = GetPlayerSpots();
                StartCoroutine(LerpToPlayerSpot(playerSpots[id].position, Constants.GetInPosTime));
            }
        }
        else if (time == 0)
        {

        }
    }
    #endregion
    #region Dice Game Mode
    if (gameManager.gameMode == GameMode.Dice)
    {
        if (numSpacesToMove != 0 && isTurn && !atIntersection)
        {
            movementProgress += movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
            nextSquare = FindNextSquare();
            ChangeCharDirection();
            while (nextSquare != null && numSpacesToMove > 0 && movementProgress >= 1.0f)
            {
                movementProgress -= 1.0f;
                if (numSpacesToMove < 0)
                {
                    currentTile = travelledTiles.Pop();
                    numSpacesToMove++;
                }
                else
                {
                    travelledTiles.Push(currentTile);
                    TriggerTilePassBy();
                    currentTile = nextSquare;
                    numSpacesToMove--;
                }
                if (numSpacesToMove == 0 && !atIntersection)
                {
                    HandleTyleType(currentTile);
                    // nextSquare = FindNextSquare();
                    nextSquare = null;
                    currDir = PlayerStatus.Still;
                    SetAnimatorBools();
                }
                if(currentTile.tyleType == TyleType.IntersectionTyle)
                {
                    atIntersection = true;
                }

            }

        }
        if (atIntersection && numSpacesToMove != 0)
        {
            //enable direction buttons here. Maybe! Or do nothing and wait for user input
            Debug.Log("Waiting for user to press direction button");
        }
        if (nextSquare != null)
        {
            transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(currentTile.transform.position, nextSquare.transform.position, movementProgress);
            currDir = PlayerStatus.Moving;
            SetAnimatorBools();
        }
        else
        {
            movementProgress = 0;
            Transform[] playerSpots = GetPlayerSpots();
            StartCoroutine(LerpToPlayerSpot(playerSpots[id].position, Constants.GetInPosTime));
        }
    }
    #endregion

}
```

Comment: By _reusing_ you mean copy&paste ;-] let's see what can be done...

Comment: yes that is what I mean. I scraped this yesterday just to have it work but now my whole class feels ugly because of it. Thank you for the help ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't find any common denominator in both `if`s. They are similar but too different. You could however refactor them into separate methods:

```
void Update()
{
    switch (gameManager.gameMode) 
    {
        case GameMode.Target:
            UpdateTarget();
            break;
        case GameMode.Dice:
            UpdateTarget();
            break;
        // the compiler will complain without it
        default:
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(
                "Invalid game mode: " + gameManager.gameMode);
    }    
}

void UpdateTarget() 
{
    // ...
}

void UpdateDice() 
{ 
    // ...
}
```

---

I'll go to hell for this ;-) but often when I have `if/else if` conditions like this one:

```
if (currentTile != targetTile && time == 0)
{
    hasToSkipTurn = true;
    Transform[] playerSpots = GetPlayerSpots();
    StartCoroutine(LerpToPlayerSpot(playerSpots[id].position, Constants.GetInPosTime));
    HandleTyleType(currentTile);
    targetTile = currentTile;
}
else if (currentTile == targetTile)
{
    HandleTyleType(currentTile);
    // nextSquare = FindNextSquare();
    nextSquare = null;
    currDir = PlayerStatus.Still;
    SetAnimatorBools();
}
```

I construct them in this way to avoid comments and give each condition a clear name:

```
var canSomething = currentTile != targetTile && time == 0; 
if (canSomething)
{
    hasToSkipTurn = true;
    Transform[] playerSpots = GetPlayerSpots();
    StartCoroutine(LerpToPlayerSpot(playerSpots[id].position, Constants.GetInPosTime));
    HandleTyleType(currentTile);
    targetTile = currentTile;
}
else
{
    var canSomethingElse = currentTile == targetTile; 
    if (canSomethingElse)
    {
        HandleTyleType(currentTile);
        // nextSquare = FindNextSquare();
        nextSquare = null;
        currDir = PlayerStatus.Still;
        SetAnimatorBools();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I was stuck with trying to find a common thing as well. Nice refactoring idea I already have a private method region in the same class so the logic goes there.

Comment: I'm glad. ;-) as far as other aspects of your code are concerned there is not much to comment on. Good variable names, everything is clear to me. However you may consider to better describe the conditions inside `if`s and use a helper variable like `var canMove = currentTile != targetTile && time != 0 && !waitingForCard && isTurn` or whatever name makes sense for them.

Comment: I honestly did not know you can do that. Thanks again I will look into making the conditions clearer.